# Constructing a template for mathematical examples in an article written in Bangla

Tags: amsmath, examples

I'm currently trying to write an Bangla article containing many examples. For better understanding, here is an example of task in the figure.

[image: ![enter image description here]

You will notice here:

- An increment of Bangla numerals.
- Example title contains bold and italic formatting.
- All text inside example is left aligned.
- A small gap between title and text.
- A black square at the end of the last line.

However, I'm finding it very difficult to make an easy typesetting for this. I tried to make an template for all examples here, like:

```
\begin{example}[যোগ করো: ৫২৮৯+৩৭২৬]
text..
\end{example}
```

I tried some idea to do that, but no organized solution. **Can you help me out to make an organized template?**

I am using `babel` package for Bangla:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
% \babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}

% bangla numerals
\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

% fix `matra` in bangla text
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
 \def\bbl@mapdir#1{%
   {\def\languagename{#1}%
    \let\bbl@ifrestoring\@firstoftwo % To avoid font warning
    \bbl@switchfont
    \ifnum\fontid\font>\z@
      \directlua{
        Babel.locale_props[\the\csname bbl@id@@#1\endcsname]%
              ['/\bbl@prefontid'] = \fontid\font\space}%
    \fi}}}%
\makeatother
```

As it is a large document, I'm only providing related text:

```
উদাহরণ ১.১ যোগ করো: ৫২৮৯+৩৭২৬

৫২৮৯+৩৭২৬
= (৫৩০০-১১) + (৩৭০০+২৬)
= ৯০০০+(-১১+২৬)
= ৯০১৫

এখানে দুটি সংখ্যাকে রাউন্ড করা হয়েছে।   

উদাহরণ ১.২ যোগ করো: ৯৩২৭ + ৪১৯

৯৩২৭ + ৪১৯
= ৯৩০০ + ২৭ + ৪০০ + ১৯
= ৯৭০০ + ৫৬
= ৯৭৫৬

এখানে দুটো সংখ্যার সাথে অতিরিক্ত দুটি সংখ্যা যোগ করা হয়েছে।
```

Comment: While I do not read Bangla, it appears that the last line in each of your examples is text rather than a calculation, in which case you can place a black square at the end of the last line of the example by writing `\hfill\(\blacksquare\)` at the end of the text.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Actually I am looking for the whole thing. I can even do it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an environment of some sort, or perhaps nested environments, depending on what you want to make as constant text, and what will be parameters and therefore variable.

Example: equations in the body of the environment, plus three parameters to be specified: the instruction, the number items, the conclusion.

A counter linked to the section number counts the examples. Because the class is `book` class, there is also a chapter level, so first example is 1.1.1

[image: Example of examples]

Spacing before and after can be done inside the environment definition, for example.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
% \babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}

% bangla numerals
\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

% fix `matra` in bangla text
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
 \def\bbl@mapdir#1{%
   {\def\languagename{#1}%
    \let\bbl@ifrestoring\@firstoftwo % To avoid font warning
    \bbl@switchfont
    \ifnum\fontid\font>\z@
      \directlua{
        Babel.locale_props[\the\csname bbl@id@@#1\endcsname]%
              ['/\bbl@prefontid'] = \fontid\font\space}%
    \fi}}}%
\makeatother

\newcounter{examplenum}[section]

\newenvironment{example}[3]{%1=instruction, 2=items, 3=result
%begin the environment
\def\myx{#3}
\refstepcounter{examplenum}
\textbf{উদাহরণ} \thesection.\theexamplenum\hspace{1ex} \textit{#1}: #2
\medskip
%body of environment (the equations)
}{%
%close the environment
\medskip
\myx\hfill\(\blacksquare\)
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Test}
Manual:

\textbf{উদাহরণ} ১.১ \textit{যোগ করো}: ৫২৮৯+৩৭২৬

\medskip
৫২৮৯+৩৭২৬

= (৫৩০০-১১) + (৩৭০০+২৬)

= ৯০০০+(-১১+২৬)

= ৯০১৫

\medskip
এখানে দুটি সংখ্যাকে রাউন্ড করা হয়েছে।\hfill\(\blacksquare\)


\bigskip
Environment:

\begin{example}{যোগ করো}{৫২৮৯+৩৭২৬}{এখানে দুটি সংখ্যাকে রাউন্ড করা হয়েছে।}

৫২৮৯+৩৭২৬

= (৫৩০০-১১) + (৩৭০০+২৬)

= ৯০০০+(-১১+২৬)

= ৯০১৫

\end{example}


\begin{example}{যোগ করো}{৫২৮৯+৩৭২৬}{এখানে দুটি সংখ্যাকে রাউন্ড করা হয়েছে।}

৫২৮৯+৩৭২৬

= (৫৩০০-১১) + (৩৭০০+২৬)

= ৯০০০+(-১১+২৬)

= ৯০১৫

\end{example}

\end{document}
```